# Optimization problem. Objective function not differentiable

Tags: calculus, optimization

I am looking at an optimization problem and I am stuck at this point:

minimize: $\pi \max{[(x_1-a_i)^2 + (x_2-b_i)^2]} - \pi \min{[(x_1-a_i)^2 + (x_2-b_i)^2]}$

which is a problem in two variables $x_1,x_2$ and the objective function has to be continuously differentiable. However, the objective function is not differentiable (according to the solution).

My question is, why isn't it differentiable?

Comment: Are you sure it is correctly written? both your max and min functions have only one argument each.

Comment: How many points $(a_i,b_i)$ are involved?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example: When the two points $(\pm1,0)$ are given then
$$\max\{(x-1)^2+y^2,(x+1)^2+y^2\}=x^2+1+y^2+2|x|$$
and similarly
$$\min\{(x-1)^2+y^2,(x+1)^2+y^2\}=x^2+1+y^2-2|x|\ .$$
It follows that your objective function
$$f(x,y)=\pi \cdot 4|x|$$
is not differentiable along the $y$-axis.